# Did Sita pray to Agni not to burn hanuman's tail when ravana's people set it on fire?

Tags: hanuman, sita, agni

I remember this as folklore - but is it present in any major Ramayana version?

Answer (score 4):

The **Valmiki Ramayana**, **[Sundara Kanda, Sarga 53](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga53/sundara_53_frame.htm)** narrates the incident of Sita praying to Agni to not burn Hanuman.

When the Rakshasis hear of Ravana setting Hanuman's tail on fire, they inform Sita Devi of this incident.

> yaḥ tvayā kṛta samvādaḥ sīte tāmra mukhaḥ kapiḥ || 
> lāngūlena pradīptena sa eṣa pariṇīyate | 
> "Oh Sita! The red-faced monkey who you were talking to is being taken around the city with a burning tail". (VR 5.53.25b-26a)

When she hears of this, Sita prays to the Deity of Fire in four verses.

> yadi asti pati śuśrūṣā yadi asti caritam tapaḥ || 
> yadi ca asti eka patnītvam śīto bhava hanūmataḥ | 
> yadi kaścit anukrośaḥ tasya mayi asti dhīmataḥ || 
> yadi vā bhāgya śeṣam me śīto bhava hanūmataḥ | 
> yadi mām vṛtta sampannām tat samāgama lālasām || 
> sa vijānāti dharma ātmā śīto bhava hanūmataḥ | 
> yadi mām tārayati āryaḥ sugrīvaḥ satya samgaraḥ || 
> asmāt duhkhān mahābāhuḥ śīto bhava hanūmataḥ | 
>
> "If I have performed service to my husband, if I have undergone penance, if I am a faithful wife, be cool towards Hanuman.
> If the wise Rama has some mercy towards me, if I have any good fortune remaining, be cool towards Hanuman.
> If that paragon of Dharma understands me to be steadfast in virtue and awaiting his arrival, be cool towards Hanuman. 
> If the valorous and noble Sugriva is (spending his efforts towards) rescuing me from this sorrow, be cool towards Hanuman." (VR 5.53.28b-32a)

Accepting this prayer (or rather, command) of Sita Devi, Agni became cool like ice towards Hanuman and didn't burn his tail.

> tataḥ tīkṣṇa arciḥ avyagraḥ pradakṣiṇa śikho analaḥ || 
> jajvāla mṛga śāva akṣyāḥ śaṃsann iva śivam kapeḥ | 
> hanumajjanakaścāpi pucchānalayuto.anilaḥ || 
> vavau svāsthyakaro devyāḥ prāleyānilaśītalaḥ | 
>
> "Then the fire, burning around Hanuman, shone with bright flames as if assuring the doe-eyed Sita of the well-being of Hanuman.
> Hanuman's father Vayu too aided Agni's efforts on Hanuman's tail by blowing cool breeze, and providing solace to the Goddess (Sita)." (VR 5.53.32b-34a).